# javascript - unknown number of objects to create from one class

Tags: javascript, class, oop, object

I have a class from which i can create object:

```
function myClass () { 
  ...
}

var obj = new myClass()
var obj2 = new myClass()
```

Each object represents one connection. It stores some important data ie connection id and so on. It works fine until i know number of connections, but in fact there may be 0 connections or 1000 connections. How can I easily put creating of objects into "for" loop to automatize process of making objects? Each object should be easily accessible so some convention of naming objects also is needed. I am surprised that i cant find such a solution in google. Any help would be apreciated.

I mean sth like this:

```
function myClass () { 
  ...
}

for (i=0; i<sth.length; i++)
  var obj$i = new myClass()
}
```

Kalreg.

Comment: I'd suggest an array, or use an object as a sort of associative array.

Comment: So use an array or an object with a for loop.

Comment: @depperm What are you talking about.... OP is not using ES6 above...

Comment: @depperm I guess his code seems ok under ES5 terms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myClass(i)
{
    this.id = i;
}

var n = 1000, objs = {};
for (var i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    objs[i] = new myClass(i);
}

console.log(objs[25].id);
```

Comment: redundantly redundant, `id` is always the same as the key in the `objs` object, there's no point in using both

Comment: I added "id" just to show how he can access any object and use their attributes.

Comment: Can you check the code please? last line returns "undefined" for me instead of "25" i guess

Comment: Is there a way to change MyClass properties from another function using sth like myClass.counter = 10 ?

Comment: @Kalreg You can use JavaScript prototype property. `myClass.prototype.counter = 10;`  `console.log(objs[5].counter);`

Answer (score 2):

Simple loop and push to an array:

```
var myStuff = [];
for (var i=0; i<sth.length; i++)
    myStuff.push(new myClass());
}
console.log(myStuff[5]);
```

or an Object with named keys

```
var myStuff = {};
for (var i=0; i<sth.length; i++)
    myStuff["foo"+i] = new myClass();
}
console.log(myStuff["foo5"]);
```

or an Array with map because I am waiting for a build...

```
var count = 15;
var myStuff = Array.apply(null, Array(count)).map(function () {return new myClass();});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with *OOP in Javascript* and ... if you want to control the number of your instantiated objects and be able to access any object by its name, consider this approach:

```
function MyClass(){
   ...
   MyClass.count++;
}
MyClass.count = 0;   // static property (stores number of objects)
MyClass.objectStorage = {};   // object storage

MyClass.createObjects = function(number){   // static method (creates new objects)
    var obj = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < number; i++){
        obj = new MyClass();
        MyClass.objectStorage["object"+ MyClass.count] = obj;
    }
};

MyClass.createObjects(10); // let's create 10 objects
MyClass.createObjects(5); // and some more

console.log(MyClass.count);  // check how many objects were created
console.log(MyClass.objectStorage["object12"]);  // accessing distinct object by name
```

Comment: MyClass.objectStorage["object12"] is the only way to getting to my object? isnt there something more clear like object12.prop ?

Comment: this approach is good for gaining clear global scope and lets you to relate your logic to MyClass, cause you can have different custom types represented by custom constructors